# Is it possible running SharePoint Foundation 2010 on the following environment?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if the following environment is supported by SharePoint Foundation 2010:

- OS: **Windows Server 2003 R2**
- DB: **SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition** (with license model for CPU)

If not officially supported by Microsoft, do you known any workarounds that allow me to install it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported and unfortunately it is not going to be possible for you to make it work unless you run some sort of virtualization platform on top of Windows Server 2003.

SharePoint 2010 **requires** Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 as its base OS. It will work with SQL Server 2005 as long as you have it patched to the correct level (at least SP3 and I think there is also a recommended cumulative update to apply as well), but Windows Server 2003 R2 is completely not possible.

John